# Want to display a table with 100 data items (10 fields with 10 records) with each value having it's own background color

Tags: ms-access

I have a table of 10 fields each are numbers and the test data consists of 10 records of data.  The possible numbers can be any of 1,000 colors depending upon the data so doing 1,000 conditional formatting rules is not practical so how can I display this 10x10 (100 data items) with each of the 100 data items have a different color based upon some formula? Like 12.23 = Color #32C1 and 34.00 = color #1234, etc.

So a user would see a 10x10 matrix of 100 different colors (assuming each data item is different from all others

Comment: Use the right tool. This sounds like a perfect task for Excel.

Comment: You could do it with a report, using the Format event.

Comment: What is this data? Will it be numbers between 1 and 1000? Limited to 2 decimals?